# passing envvars to docker containers in GoCD

Tags: docker, environment-variables, go-cd

We have a docker container and the program that runs inside expects a number of envvars to be set. There are several ways to do this and I was curious as to what the correct way is:

1- put envvars in a config repo, add it as a material, use docker --env-file flag to pass the file. Cons: seems like overkill for passing 10 envvars.

2- define envvars in the job configuration tab. Export them during docker build. Cons: Every new job would have to manually set the envvars, adding an envvar would require changing all jobs in one place.

3- define envvars in the job configuration tab. Pass them during docker run using -e flag. Cons: Every new job would have to manually set the envvars, adding an envvar would require changing each job in two places.

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

There's another option: Write a small shell script that passes all environment variables to `docker` that start with a certain prefix.

For example, you could make it turn `DOCKER_A=a` and `DOCKER_B=b` into `-e A=a -e B=b`, and call it as

```
docker $(./munge_env_vars) ...
```

Then you can put all your environment variables in one place (either in the GoCD config, or in a shell script under version control that you can `source`), and no need to modify two places when you add another env variable.